# Put dynamic data in echosign document using merge data?

Tags: widget, echosign

We have a use case where the we would like our clients to sign their contracts on our website.
So we are going to create widgets and embed them in our webpages. The thing I'm struggling with is adding dynamic content into the documents using Merge Data.

My document has tags like {{firstname}} and when creating a widget I use

```
"mergeFieldInfo": {
      "fieldName": "firstname",
      "defaultValue": "abc"
 }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here??

I'm following the Echosign's api guide : https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v2;jsessionid=34BFBC3886E48E109EB7A36CDB9E91CD.ord-prod-app15#!/tokens/_post_0

And my document is transient document since Echosign does not allow library documents to be used while creating a widget, such a shame. :/

Comment: Ok, got it. I was missing role in my tags.
So tag should be like {{firstname_es_:signer}}

Comment: It is a shame you cannot use Library Documents. Very frustrating actually. Additionally, you should post your comment as an answer to your question. You can accept your own answers :)

Comment: I have a question: you said your document's text tag was `{{firstname_es_signer}}`. Was your JSON field name still `"fieldName: "firstname"` or was it also `firstname_es_:signer`, or something different?